# How do I sort files on multiple filename parts?

Tags: bash, files, sort

I have filenames in the format `STR_NUM1_STR_NUM2_NUM3_NUM4_STR.dat`. `NUM1` repeats for many files. I want to sort the files first based on `NUM1` and within each NUM1 group, I want the files to be sorted based on `NUM4`. How can I do this in bash?

```
Tmp1_24298_Data_545_547_63359_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_667_669_63637_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_683_685_63517_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_695_697_63557_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_701_703_63437_Sample.dat
Tmp1_28703_Data_545_547_63833_Sample.dat
Tmp1_28703_Data_667_669_64111_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_683_685_63951_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_695_697_64031_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_701_703_63910_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_545_547_64306_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_667_669_64545_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_683_685_64424_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_295_697_64505_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_701_703_64344_Sample.dat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, with `_` as the field separator, you want to sort on the numbers in the second and sixth fields.  In that case, and if the filenames are in a file called `filenames`, one file per line, then use:

```
$ sort -nt_ -k2,2 -k6,6 filenames
Tmp1_24298_Data_545_547_63359_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_701_703_63437_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_683_685_63517_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_695_697_63557_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_667_669_63637_Sample.dat
Tmp1_28703_Data_545_547_63833_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_701_703_63910_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_683_685_63951_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_695_697_64031_Sample.dat
Tmp1_28703_Data_667_669_64111_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_545_547_64306_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_701_703_64344_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_683_685_64424_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_295_697_64505_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_667_669_64545_Sample.dat
```

If the files are in the current directory, the POSIX solution is:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.dat' | sort -nt_ -k2,2 -k6,6
Tmp1_24298_Data_545_547_63359_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_701_703_63437_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_683_685_63517_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_695_697_63557_Sample.dat
Tmp1_24298_Data_667_669_63637_Sample.dat
Tmp1_28703_Data_545_547_63833_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_701_703_63910_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_683_685_63951_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28703_Data_695_697_64031_Sample.dat
Tmp1_28703_Data_667_669_64111_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_545_547_64306_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_701_703_64344_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_683_685_64424_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_295_697_64505_Sample.dat
Tmp2_28707_Data_667_669_64545_Sample.dat
```

#### How it works

- `-n` tells `sort` to sort numerically.
- `-t_` tells `sort` to use `_` as the field separator.
- `-k2,2 -k6,6`  tells `sort` to sort first of on the second field and, if the second fields are equal, then to sort on the sixth field.

#### GNU solution (handles filenames containing newlines)

To handle filenames which themselves contain newlines, we need to use NUL-separation.  That means using `-print0` with `find` and `-z` with `sort` and then, to make the output printable for display here, converting NUL to newlines with `tr`:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.dat' -print0 | sort -znt_ -k2,2 -k6,6 | tr '\0' '\n'
./Tmp1_24298_Data_545_547_63359_Sample.dat
./Tmp1_24298_Data_701_703_63437_Sample.dat
./Tmp1_24298_Data_683_685_63517_Sample.dat
./Tmp1_24298_Data_695_697_63557_Sample.dat
./Tmp1_24298_Data_667_669_63637_Sample.dat
./Tmp1_28703_Data_545_547_63833_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28703_Data_701_703_63910_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28703_Data_683_685_63951_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28703_Data_695_697_64031_Sample.dat
./Tmp1_28703_Data_667_669_64111_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28707_Data_545_547_64306_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28707_Data_701_703_64344_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28707_Data_683_685_64424_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28707_Data_295_697_64505_Sample.dat
./Tmp2_28707_Data_667_669_64545_Sample.dat
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! How do I then replace NUM4 with numbers starting from 1? That is, within each NUM1 group, I want my output to be piped to files that have similar names but NUM4 replaced with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...

Comment: @user360413 To replace NUM4 with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc., try: `sort -nt_ -k2,2 -k6,6 filenames | awk -F_ '{$6=NR} 1' OFS=_`